# How to use sendgrid with log4j2 SMTP appender?

Tags: java, log4j2, sendgrid

I tried log4j2 SMTP appender with my gmail configuration and it worked well.  But sendgrid doesn't give any SMTP like configurations. We have apikey. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [use your API key to send via SMTP](https://sendgrid.com/docs/Classroom/Send/How_Emails_Are_Sent/api_keys.html#-Via-SMTP). For SMTP username use the string `apikey` and put your API key in as the password. Host is `smtp.sendgrid.net` and you can use several ports but 587 is recommended. [More info](https://sendgrid.com/docs/Classroom/Basics/Email_Infrastructure/smtp_ports.html).